# R - choosing rows with maximum counts

Tags: r

I've got data like below:

```
surname name
a       b,a,c,e
b       a,b,c,d,f
c       a,d,c,e
d       a,c,e,f,j,k
e       b,d,e,g
```

Now I have to change the subset of three surnames (a,b,c or b,c,d or etc...) that are associated with the largest number of names. In another words, if I change surname a,b and e as a result I obtain 6 names (a,b,c,d,e,g) but if I change ab, and c I get only four names. The goal is to obtain as much names as possible by choosing the same surname.

The output should be similar to below (for all possible combinations of surname in triplets):

```
chosen_surname number_of_explained_unique_names
a,b,c          6
a,c,d          8
a,d,e          9
```

Is there any simple way to obtain this? I though about select all possible combination of surnames and then count the number of names, but my data.frame is rather big (about 1000 rows), so it takes too long. What can I do?

Comment: what is the data type of the name column ? Is it character or a list column containing vectors ? it will be clearer if you include a `dput` of your data (`dput(your_df`)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper name column contains strings with characters (not list)

Comment: it's not completely clear to me what you want, can you include your expected output ?

Comment: Better **SHOW** your DESIRED OUTPUT in your Question.

Comment: @anba, please include it in your question, not comments

Comment: @ Moody_Mudskipper @Andre Elrico sorry, I've edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether this is faster:

data: (please provide reproducible Data in your next question (see `dput()`))

```
df1<-data.frame(surname=letters[1:5],
                  name=c("b,a,c,e",
                  "a,b,c,d,f",
                  "a,d,c,e",
                  "a,c,e,f,j,k",
                  "b,d,e,g"),stringsAsFactors=F)
```

code:

```
library(magrittr)    
#chosen_sname=c("a,b,c","a,c,d","a,d,e")
chosen_sname=combn(df1$surname,3) %>% data.frame(.,stringsAsFactors=F) %>% sapply(function(x){paste0(x,collapse=",")}) %>% unname


namesList = df1$name %>% strsplit(",")
colsList  = chosen_sname %>% strsplit(",") %>% lapply(function(x)match(x,df1$surname))

sapply(colsList,function(x){namesList[x] %>% unlist %>% unique %>% length}) %>% data.frame(chosen_sname,length=.,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

result:

```
#   chosen_sname length
#1         a,b,c      6
#2         a,b,d      8
#3         a,b,e      7
#4         a,c,d      8
#5         a,c,e      6
#6         a,d,e      9
#7         b,c,d      8
#8         b,c,e      7
#9         b,d,e      9
#10        c,d,e      9
```

please note:

1. for this to work your variables need to be named like in the **data:** section:
2. change `chosen_sname` to look at other name combinations!
3. your example contains an error. For "a,d,e" its 9.

Comment: Thanks, it seems faster. But - I need to obtain the "length" balue for all possible combinations of surnames (not only these three sample). How should I change the first line (combn function?)?

Comment: What do you mean by "all possible combinations"? Of 3 combinations?

Comment: In this example - for a,b,c; a,b,d; a,b,e; b,c,d; b,c,e; c,d,e; a,d,e; a,c,d; a,d,e;a,c,e. I have to check the "length" for all possible selection of three surnames. And  my real data contain more that 100 rows, that is inconvenient to just give it in the vector.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. And I corrected my error in my example.

Comment: Glad to help. Interesting problem.